# Reading JSON data into the correct data structure

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to load JSON data using d3. The data structure I'm trying to genrate is:

```
var dataset = [[{"x": 10.2, "y": 120.1}, {"x": 20.2, "y": 20.1},{"x": 30.2, "y": 10.2}, {"x": 40.2, "y": 20.2}]]
```

The D3/JS code I'm using looks like this:

```
var dataset = [[]];
d3.json("/data", function (error, data) {

    for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        dataset[0].push({"x": data[i].x, "y": data[i].y});
    }
});
```

When I look at the results in the console, the data structure I'm trying to generate looks like this:

```
dataset = [Array[4]]
dataset[0] = [Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

The data structure I generate with the above D3 function looks like this:

```
dataset = [Array[0]]
```

When I log the data at the beginning of the call back I get this:

[image]

I can access the data by `console.log(data[0].y);`, which gives me 120.1

How can I generate a function that reads my JSON data into the correct data structure?

Comment: Don't you have to use `dataset[0].push...` instead?

Comment: Ok, what happens when you add `console.log(data)` right at the start of that callback?

Comment: Ok, updated my post to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that `d3.json()` is asynchronous (as `jQuery.ajax()` is by default).

This means that the `dataset` variable will be populated when you will receive the data. So if you try to use `dataset` without waiting for the data to be received, you will have an empty `dataset`.

The solution is to do everything using this `dataset` in the callback, which will be called on success or error. For example if you need to call a function `useDataset()` in your code you would do the following:

```
var dataset;
d3.json("/data", function (error, data) {
    // insert checking for error
    dataset = data;
    useDataset()
});
```

If you want to know more about asynchronous requests and callbacks the [`jQuery.ajax()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is great.

By the way, by doing so, you can probably remove this whole function you use to copy the data.